# Windows 7 Pro DNS issue with static IP

Tags: windows-7, windows, dns

I have been unable to solve a DNS problem I am having as follows:

I have a Windows 7 Professional (64 bit) computer running VirtualBox with a couple of Windows XP guests (not sure if this bit is relevant). After heavy file copying/transfer on both of the Windows XP machines, both the guest machines AND the host loose anything DNS related, so I cannot call anything by name, but by direct IP works fine. The only resolution is to reboot the (host) machine and it will then work OK for a while until it happens again. The only trigger to make it seem to happen quicker is to re-initiate the heavy file transfer and this then causes the DNS resolution to stop working again.

- The machine has a fixed IP address, so it isn't related to DHCP.
- I've tried the machine connected wired and wireless, no difference.
- The IP settings are manual and I have tried giving it the DNS settings of the router (normal settings) and I have also tried giving it Google's DNS servers (8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4). No difference.
- It seems to happen (sooner) during heavy traffic.
- Other Windows 7 machines in the network work fine (though they are Home version, not Pro).
- ONLY DNS fails, direct IP works OK.
- Reboot seems only solution at the moment.

I am now lost as to what to try to resolve this issue, I do not really want to reload Windows 7 as it is a relatively new install... I have read about issues with wired connections on my router (BT Home Hub 2.0) so tried a wireless connection, still the same.

Here is my ipconfig /all (it shows the BT Home Hub router DNS settings, but it also failed with Google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 entered here and also with the routers 192.168.1.254 (default).

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\G>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : e1
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 30-85-A9-AD-07-81
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::59f:484a:827f:42ba%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.87(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 238060969
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-39-2B-4D-30-85-A9-AD-07-81

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 217.32.171.21
                                       213.120.234.30
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-00-28-56
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8d2d:7418:381b:8dc0%15(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 336068647
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-39-2B-4D-30-85-A9-AD-07-81

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{486D4DCC-9CB7-417E-A796-596E0E6B1D54}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{67455999-75A5-436E-9EAC-12B093363132}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\Users\G>
```

Any ideas where to look, or what other info to provide for any assistance?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, router IP is 192.168.1.254 which is the gateway address entered.

Comment: What names are you trying to connect to them with?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I do not understand, what do you mean?

I can't access, for example, www.google.com from either the host or any of the guest machines. But if I use Googles IP address, I can get the site fine.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. I thought you were having trouble contacting between the VM's and host by their names. After it fails, what is the output of `ipconfig /all` after it starts to fail? Does it work again after the file transfer finishes?

Comment: No problem! The output of ipconfig /all is the same both before and after the problem. The files transfers have not yet completed, so every time I reboot they start from where they left off. It has not yet been able to complete the task as it fails before it completes. No task or command I have made has been able to get it to work again, only a reboot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: (I think the ipconfig /all is the same because I use static, not DHCP?)

Comment: It has just failed again and I have seen this in the Event Viewer and I'm wondering if it is related? I tried restarting it, but it did not make it work again:

Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          11/01/2014 19:00:39
Event ID:      7036
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      e1
Description:
The WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service service entered the stopped state.

Comment: Did you solve this or did the transfer end up working?

Comment: At the moment, after hours(!) of investigation, it is pointing towards a problem with NetDrive which I use to map FTP servers to a drive letter. I stopped using it and the problem has not come back again since... I do not know what causes this behavior though. Thank you.